# git reset HEAD~1 vs git branch -f mainline HEAD~1

Tags: git, git-branch, git-reset

Assuming, current branch is mainline. mainline and HEAD pointer are pointing to the latest commit.

```
git reset HEAD~1
git branch -f mainline HEAD~1
```

To the best of my understanding both the commands will :

bring mainline pointer to a previous commit along with HEAD pointer

Which one should we use from the above two and why?

Edit : As pointed in comments current branch cannot be the same for using the git branch -f mainline HEAD ~1 command.

Comment: `git branch -f mainline HEAD~1` => "fatal: Cannot force update the current branch."

Comment: as noted by @phd: the difference is that `git reset` will only work on the active branch, while `git branch -f ...` will *refuse* to change the active branch. Otherwise, both commands will result in bringing the target branch to `HEAD~1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as noted by @phd in his comment: the difference is that `git reset` will only work on the active branch, while git `branch -f ...` will *refuse* to change the active branch.

Otherwise, both commands will result in bringing the target branch to `HEAD~1`